# Uploading Documents Choose Destination folder does not work

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, document-library

I have a document library with at least 20 folders in it. When I go to the library to upload a document, the upload document popup window does render properly.
- I then click on the choose destination, this renders correctly.  I can select a destination folder and click ok. However, the destination folder is not populated in the field. The result no matter what I select is always /.

How would I correct this?
Is this a problem with what java version is installed on the browser?

Comment: which browser are you using, there are issues using SharePoint on any browser other then Internet Explorer and is it possible to add a screenshot please ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and it was due to the doc library having a setting (in the Advanced screen) to not allow new folders (the "*Make "New Folder" command available?*" option).

Setting this to "Yes" fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

is the site created using a blank site template?

if so you might have features that are not activated that would restrict the destination folder from being viewed and why you would see /.

can you activate the following within features: Metadata Navigation and Filtering

Now check to see if it works properly?

I had this problem in 2010 when creating a blank site ;).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. This problem occurs on all of my sites regardless of the Template. However, I did as requested. I activated the Metadata Navigation and Filtering
The choose button is still displaying
When selecting "choose Folder" I am able to select the folder. Click ok. However, the path is still not populate. Typeing a folder works. But to have my users do this may cause problems. I was just wondering if there was anyone else facting this problem.
Is there a setting or version of java or IE addon that would probably cause this?